# Excel 2010 CTRL+SHIFT+L. Not working

Tags: excel-2010

I apologize if asked/answered - but I truly did search....

In excel CTRL+Shift+L is not working;  when I press the key sequence and the cursor spins and comes back without having accomplished turning on the filters or anything visible to me.  This is the only shortcut that is not working so I did not know if I redefined it - but could not tell what it was currently defined as,  I had the IT guys repair the install - All with no luck...

I would love to debug what CTRL+Shift+L does when I hit it - but could not figure out if that was possible...

Totally at wits end - - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please try Alt+A+T. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Please elaborate what that combination does.

Comment: ALT+A shows all the shortcuts in the ribbon pane & T is shortcut for filter.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was Radeon Overlay which had the same hotkey for longing performance metrics. Just end whichever other programs you have running and see after each one if it gets fixed. Or try running excel in safe mode (Run excel.exe /safe) maybe the issue is an add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 2010, but I do have 2013 and Ctrl+Shift_L works in 2013.  Couple of things I can think of - one, do you have hidden cells?  Second, when you hover over the filter button in the ribbon, does it still show Ctrl+Shift+L as the shortcut?  Also, when I press that key combination, the ribbon indicates that the spreadsheet is currently filtered, does yours show that after you've pressed the shortcut?

Comment: So - my ribbon still says CTRL-SHIFT-L is filter when hovering and no hidden cells - - it is as though it was redefined to perform another function - ribbon does not indicate filtered after the key sequence.  Tx!

Comment: Does it show as filtered after you click the filter button?

Comment: Yes- the filter button is working as expected when clicked - drop downs appear

Comment: You can create shortcuts for Macros.  Do you have any defined?

Comment: Is the data on this spreadsheet special (pasted from somewhere else)?  Does this key combination fail in all spreadsheets or just one?  I get an error in 2013 in some cases where it says this cell can't be filtered because there is no data in the range.  Maybe 2010 is failing but not telling you why.  Is your cursor on the top row when you press Ctrl+Shift+L?  That's a lot of questions.  Can you answer them all?

Comment: thank you everyone  - I started excel in safe mode "excel /safe" and without the add-ins I am good - not I have to find out why the one is killing my shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is pretty old, but I ran into the same problem in the past couple of days and it was very frustrating.

It turned out that I had assigned the same shortcut to a Macro and completely forgot about it. The workbook containing the Macro was always open in the background and it prevented even other workbooks, without the Macro, to use the Filter shortcut.

So if you still have the problem, try checking if any of your open workbooks have macros and if so, check to see if ctrl+shift+L is assigned to any of them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility... If you have two tabs selected at the bottom of the page it will not let you use that shortcut.  You will not even let you use the sort/filter button at the top of the toolbar. You will be able to tell if you have two tabs selected by looking at the bottom of the window at the tabs.  Click one of them or off of them to go back to only having one selected.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt check for excel but for sublime yes ..
tried https://www.nextofwindows.com/troubleshoot-control-shift-l-stopped-working-in-sublime. 
may be this works for excel too, as amd's radeon  is using ctrl+shift+l hot key.

Comment: We encourage linking to external sources but we have zero control over edits or if that site exists in 10 years or 10 minutes. Consequently, we also need the most relevant content in the answers. If you can put it in and @ me I'll upvote your answer. If you don't you will see some down votes eventually for this. "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." See "Provide context for links" in the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article here. ;-)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. It doesn't address the title or the concept in the content or the related app/language flags. You will want to delete this answer before you get a bunch of down-votes or fix it to match the question. To further clarify, when someone asks about a specific language or app you can potentially answer usefully with a different language/app like you did here. However, that is usually considered a low quality answer even when it is a useful answer. Generally you want to avoid it so you don't lose reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, turns out radeon software is using the same hotkeys for performance logging. Resolved it via:

1. Open Radeon Software (usually it's on the hidden icons on the taskbar)
2. Go to Hotkeys tab and reassign a new hotkey or just delete it

Answer (score 0):

Download Master was blocking "Ctrl+Shift+L"

Answer (score -2):

Do you have slicers connected to the table? If so, you need to delete slicers first.

Comment: Can you rephrase this to sound less like a question?